# how to validate recyclerView items when click on button in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i have 2 EditText in recyclerView item. for example, first name and last name!
and i have fragment, have this recyclerView and a button!
i want when clicked on button, validate all EditText in recyclerView items
and saved users to ArrayList.
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zQTO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This, It's work on my application

```
//validation controls
public boolean Validatioin() {
    if (first_name.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
        first_name.setError(getString(R.string.valid_first_name));
        return false;
    } else if (lest_name.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
        lest_name.setError(getString(R.string.valid_first_name));
        return false;
    } else {
            strFirstName = first_name.getText().toString();
            strLastName = lest_name.getText().toString();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

// interface

```
public interface user_details {
    void userDetails(String firstName,String 
    Lastname);
}
```

// in Adapter class

```
userDetails.userDetails(strFirstName,strLastName);
```

// constructor

```
private userDetails userDetails;
public adapterName(Context context,userDetails userDetails)
{
    this.userDetails = userDetails;
}
```